# Request id of input field with type text

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

I need to get the id's of my dynamicly generated text boxes. Using c#, ASP.NET, VisualStudio 2012 MVC 4

Code in cshtml file:

```
@foreach (var item in productList)
{
  <input id="@item.articleNumber" name="articles" type="text"/>
}
```

Code in the controller

```
    public ActionResult bestelProducten()
    {
        string[] values = Request.Form.GetValues("articles");

        foreach (String s in values)
        {
            DialogResult d = TopMostMessageBox.Show(s, "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }       

        return View();
    }
```

Lets say we have three articles in my articleList. It will generate three inputboxes. I enter 1,2,3 in those textboxes. The dialog result will show the values of the input boxes (1,2,3). But i need the id of that textbox with each value i am getting. For example with the value 1 i need the id (id)articlenumber of that textbox and with value 2 i need the (id)article number of that textbox.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to get the IDs of the form elements that were submitted to the server in the c# code. I don't think this is possible (servers won't submit the ID), but with a few changes, you'll be able to get the result you are looking for.

I have to make a few assumptions though - feel free to comment on this if the assumptions aren't quite correct and I'll try to accomodate.

First, I'm going to make the assumption that your variable "productList" is an `IList<>` of a type that has two properties, "articleNumber" and "article". Let's call this type `Article`, and would be of the form:

```
public class Article
{
  public string article { get; set; }

  // I'm assuming it's just a string here
  public string articleNumber { get; set; } 
}
```

I'm also assuming this is not part of a model or view model that you passed to this view (if any), so I won't use any HtmlHelpers here.

You could do the following for the cshtml file:

```
@for (int i; i < productList.Count; i++)
{
  <input name="[i].articleNumber" type="hidden" value="@item.articleNumber" />
  <input name="[i].article" type="text"/>
}
```

Rather than using an ID, I use a hidden field. This way, the article number will get submitted with the article. The `[i]` parameter tells MVC that the objects are a part of a list and that `articleNumber` and `article` are part of the same object, thus keeping the number and the article together, assuming that the receiving object has these fields (which we have assumed it does). See [this article by Phill Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/) for more on model binding to a list.

Your controller action would then become:

```
public ActionResult bestelProducten(IList<Article> articles)
{
    foreach (Article a in articles)
    {
        DialogResult d = TopMostMessageBox.Show(string.Format("Article Number: {0} - Article Order: {1}", a.articleNumber, a.article), "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }       

    return View();
}
```

The `articles` parameter in the controller will automatically bind to your list of named `[i].` parameters.

I've done this off the top of my head, so it might need a bit of tweaking - but I hope this is what you were looking for.

---

**Update**: First, I got two of the parameters the wrong way around in the for loop - fixed that!

Second, hopefully I can help you a bit more fully now! Note that in the code above, you can swap `IList` for `List`, an `IList` is an interface that implements `List`. I'll continue using `List` now though.

I see what the textbox is for now. So, your `Article` actually has three fields, a third integer value, articleOrder. In that case, I would do this:

1) Create an `ArticleOrderModel` object that looks like this:

```
public class ArticleOrderModel
{
  // This is the number of your article
  public int ArticleNumber { get; set; }

  // This is the order it appears in
  public int ArticleOrder { get; set; }
}
```

2) In your view, setup your for loop like this (assuming you are using productList, as your question originally stated):

```
@for (int i; i < productList.Count; i++)
{
  <!-- Add your HtmlHelpers here as you mention -->
  @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].articleNumber);
  @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].article);

  <!-- As you are submitting to the model, you need to create form 
  elements that will submit to it. The first line provides the article 
  number, the second is your textbox --> 
  <input name="[i].articleNumber" type="hidden" value="@item.articleNumber" />
  <input name="[i].articleOrder" type="text"/>
}
```

3) Setup your controller like this:

```
public ActionResult bestelProducten(List<ArticleOrderModel> model)
{
    // Get your article list out of storage here

    foreach (ArticleOrderModel a in model)
    {
        // Here, I recommend that you put the order into the original Article objects,
        // I just will leave the original code here.
        DialogResult d = TopMostMessageBox.Show(string.Format("Article Number: {0} - Article: {1}", a.articleNumber, a.articleOrder), "Test", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }       

    return View();
}
```

I've used a seperate model for your controller action, as I got the impression you just want to display the article text, and you want an article order. The model I chose just obtains the data you need.

---

If you want to edit the article text on the same page as well, then change the parameter in the controller to be an `Article`, and just do this in your view:

```
@for (int i; i < productList.Count; i++)
{
  <!-- Add your HtmlHelpers here as you mention -->
  @Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].articleNumber);
  @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].articleNumber);
  @Html.EditorFor(x => x[i].article);
  @Html.EditorFor(x => x[i].articleOrder);
}
```

In that case, you don't need to bother with the `ArticleOrderModel`

Comment: i had to answer this topic because my comment couldn't go in this box. Sorry =( the answer is for you

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function(){
  $('[name="articles"]').each(function(){
     console.log($(this).attr("id"));
  });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/end7b/)

Answer (score 0):

@DanielNaylor productList is of type List i don't now how far that differs from IList i just stared with c# asp.net 10 weeks ago! And objects of the type Article will go in that list (articleList `List<Article>`) This view has a model from the type Article. I use html helpers in that foreach loop to show ever article in that list and add a input type myself as shown in the code. I write out every article in a tabel together with the input field. They should be able to enter a amount in the input field. I need the value of the input fields on every product and the article number from the article in the same so i can turn that in a order for those articles